# Calling a function within an object, Error: Uncaught TypeError: this.showValue is not a function

Tags: javascript

I wanted to get a better understanding of JavaScript Object but, I was unable to solve this error. On click it should call ob.say function which should display both the alert messages but, I end up getting this error "Uncaught TypeError: this.showValue is not a function".

```
var ob = {
 showValue: function() {
 alert("hello world");
},
 say: function() {
  this.showValue();
  alert("I said hello world!!!");
 }
}
document.addEventListener('click', ob.say);
```

Answer (score 0):

You must [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) your function so that `this`, in `say`, is the right object:

```
document.addEventListener('click', ob.say.bind(ob));
```